# GreenDAO Left Join

Tags: android, orm, greendao

Consider I have a model :
Company 1 - N Person

I want to display a list of persons with their names and their company's name. 
But not every person has a company.

I order to avoid that every call to `person.getCompany()` results in a new SQL query so I was thinking about adding a join :

```
QueryBuilder<Person> queryBuilder = session.getPersonDao().queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.join(PersonDao.Properties.CompanyId, Company.class);
queryBuilder.list()
```

The problem is that I only get the persons with a company because the generated query uses JOIN which is equivalent to INNER JOIN. I think I would need LEFT JOIN to also get the persons without a company.

It doesn't seem GreenDAO supports LEFT JOIN right now. Is there another way to make the request without doing a raw query ?

Comment: If you are open to using a different ORM, I can suggest JDXA ORM (http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html). JDXA will fetch all the qualified Person objects and any associated Company objects. If an associated Company object does not exist, a Person object will still be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved without writing a raw query.

Here is the snippet:

```
QueryBuilder<Person> qb = userDao.queryBuilder();
List<Person> outputPersonList = userDao.queryDeep(" ", null);
```

It compiles at low level as:

```
SELECT T."_id",T."NAME",T."COMPANY_ID",T0."_id",T0."NAME" 
    FROM PERSON T 
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY T0 
    ON T."COMPANY_ID"=T0."_id"
```

Of course if the `Person` model has other relations, all of them will be fetched, so this `SQL` query would be slow.

However, it basically does, what you expect.

Comment: I don't think queryDeep() would not be very efficient in my case. And I would also need a where clause, which is somewhat equivalent to a raw query when using queryDeep().

Comment: Yes, you would need to  pass hand written Where clause similar to the one described in [Greendao samples](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/1d267398b17ec5e24afffc66e295b469718902a8/tests/DaoTest/src/androidTest/java/org/greenrobot/greendao/daotest/entity/RelationEntityTest.java#L166)

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't know how to do it with raw query:

```
String query = " LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON T.id = COMPANY.ID where SOME_CONDITIONS";
List<Person> persons = session.getPersonDao().queryRaw(query);
```

Greendao will insert `SELECT T.COLUMN_1, ... T.COLUM_N from PERSON AS T` part by itself.
So in query `T` is just alias name for `Person` table.